# How to get out of tty1 when you don't know your login and password

Tags: login, tty, virtual-console

I'm having trouble logging in to the console in Ubuntu 19.04. I need to enter a login and password. When I enter my username and password, the console rejects the login. Keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>) don't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: There's no fix we can offer for you not knowing your username and/or password.

Comment: I knom my login and password but when I etered I have erro login incorrect

Comment: That's because one or the other or both are incorrect.

Comment: Well I dumped the root right and reset the password.How do I get out of the console tty1 now?

Comment: Have you read the answer?

Comment: How do I get out of the console tty1 now?

Answer (score 1):

And where do you want to go? The desktop? If so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>  is probably where the desktop is (some desktops reside on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>  but since you already see that I assume you need tty7).

If there is no desktop on your system you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. That often is set as a reboot

Sidenote:

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> does not work but you do have a login in the future you can set this in either `/etc/inittab` with

```
 ca::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t3 -h now
```

or `/etc/init/control-alt-delete.conf` with

```
start on control-alt-delete    
exec /sbin/shutdown -h now "Control-Alt-Delete pressed"
```

Use a live session to reset your password. It likely is not what you believe it to be. See [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)